# How to create right click context menu in react bootstrap table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I need to implement context menu with react-bootstrap-table. There is no such option in this plugin. Is there a way to implement this with react-bootstrap-table?

Comment: can you explain more *need to implement context menu?* do you want to put some dropdown in any particular column ?

Comment: Whenever right click on the each row that time i want to display context menu with these options, edit, delete, duplicate ... @MayankShukla

Comment: instead of right click and option, you can put dropdown and show all the options.